# Binary Search Tree (Node.js) - SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary-search-tree

I've created a program (run through node.js) that should be able to create a binary search tree with a variety of methods (insert, remove, print, etc.). It's broken up into two separate files: Tree.js which exports the functions Tree() (and its methods) and test(); and main.js which then imports the functions and runs test().

```
module.exports = {
//Tree object with constructor
var Tree = function(){
  this.data = undefined;
  this.leftNode = undefined;
  this.rightNode = undefined;
}
//Check if tree/root is empty/undefined
Tree.prototype.isEmpty = function(){
  if (this.data === undefined){
    return true;
  }
  else {return false;}
}
//Check if tree/root has no children
Tree.prototype.isLeaf = function(){
  //check to make sure node is not undefined
  if (this.data !== undefined){
    //check to make sure both children are undefined
    if (((this.leftNode === undefined) || (this.leftNode.data === undefined))
    && ((this.rightNode === undefined) || (this.rightNode.data === undefined))){
      return true;
    }
  }
  else {return false;}
}

//Insert new value as node in tree
Tree.prototype.insert = function(input){
  //Node contains no data, assign value to current node
  if (this.data === undefined){
    this.data = input;
  }

  //Node contains data
  else {
    var nextNode = new Tree(); //new node to be added
    nextNode.data = input; //assign value to new node

    //Value is smaller than data in node
    if (input < this.data){
      //Assign value to left child if empty
      if (this.leftNode === undefined){
        this.leftNode = nextNode;
      }
      //Recursively repeat insertion procedure with left child if value already assigned
      else {
        this.leftNode.insert(input);
      }
    }
    //Value is greater or equal to data in node
    else {
      //Assign value to right child if empty
      if (this.rightNode === undefined){
        this.rightNode = nextNode;
      }
      //Recursively repeat insertion procedure with left child if value already assigned
      else {
        this.rightNode.insert(input);
      }
    }
  }
}

Tree.prototype.remove = function(input){
  //Node contains input value, wipe node
  if (this.data === input){
    this.data = undefined;
    this.leftNode = undefined;
    this.rightNode = undefined;
  }

  else if (this.isLeaf() == true){
    return;
  }

  //Node contains data
  else {
    //Value is smaller than data in node
    if (input < this.data){
      //If left child contains input, wipe left child
      if (this.leftNode.data == input){
        this.leftNode.data = undefined;
        this.leftNode.leftNode = undefined;
        this.leftNode.rightNode = undefined;
      }
      //Recursively repeat removal procedure with left child if value does not match
      else {
        this.leftNode.remove(input);
      }
    }
    //Value is greater or equal to data in node
    else {
      //If right child contains input, wipe right child
      if (this.rightNode.data == input){
        this.rightNode.data = undefined;
        this.rightNode.leftNode = undefined;
        this.rightNode.rightNode = undefined;
      }
      //Recursively repeat removal procedure with right child if value does not match
      else {
        this.rightNode.remove(input);
      }
    }
  }
}

//Find out if value is contained in tree
Tree.prototype.contains = function(input){
  //Input is contained in this node
  if (this.data == input){
    return true;
  }
  //Input has reached end of tree without finding input
  else if (this.isLeaf() == true){
    return false;
  }
  //Input is smaller than data contained in node
  else if (input < this.data){
    return this.leftChild.contains(input); //Continue searching in left child
  }
  //Input is greater than data contained in node
  else{
    return this.rightChild.contains(input);//continue searching in right child
  }
}

//return largest value in tree
Tree.prototype.findLargest = function(){
  refNode = this.root; //reference node
  //loop until reference has no right child
  while (refNode.rightChild !== undefined){
    refNode = refNode.leftChild;
  }
  //Rightmost leaf contains Largest value
  return refNode.data;
}

//return smallest value in tree
Tree.prototype.findSmallest = function(){
  refNode = this.root; //reference node
  //loop until reference has no left child
  while (refNode.leftChild !== undefined){
    refNode = refNode.leftChild;
  }
  //Leftmost leaf contains smallest value
  return refNode.data;
}
//Create copy of tree
Tree.prototype.copy = function(){
  //copy each attribute of old tree to new tree
  var nextNode = new Tree();
  nextNode.data = this.data;
  nextNode.leftNode = this.leftNode;
  nextNode.rightNode;

  //return tree copy
  return nextNode;
}

//Output all data values found in tree as an ascending string
Tree.prototype.toString = function(){
  var string = '';
  if (this.leftNode !== undefined){
    string = string + this.leftNode.toString() + ', ';
  }
  if (this.rightNode !== undefined){
    string = string + this.rightNode.toString() + ', ';
  }
  if (this.data !== undefined){
    string = string + this.data;
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }
  return string;
}

//Apply function to all data values found in tree
Tree.prototype.treeMap = function(funk){
  //Apply function to data in current node
  if (this.data !== undefined){
    this.data = funk(this.data);
    //If left child is not undefined, apply method to left child
    if (this.leftNode !== undefined){
      this.leftNode.treeMap(funk);
    }
    //If right child is not undefined, apply method to right child
    if (this.rightNode !== undefined){
      this.rightNode.treeMap(funk);
    }
  }
}

//Test Tree
var test = function() {
  console.log("Creating empty tree/node.\n")
  var spruce = new Tree();
  console.log("Is this node empty? " + this.isEmpty() + "\n");
  spruce.insert(8);
  console.log("Inserted value 8. Is node still empty? " +this.isEmpty() + "\n");
  console.log("Is this node a leaf? " + this.isLeaf() + "\n");
  spruce.insert(3);
  spruce.insert(1);
  spruce.insert(6);
  spruce.insert(4);
  spruce.insert(7);
  spruce.insert(10);
  spruce.insert(14);
  spruce.insert(13);
  console.log("Contents of tree: " + this.toString() + "\n");
  console.log("Inserted several more values. Is this node still a leaf?" + this.isLeaf() + "\n");
  console.log("Inserted value 14. Does tree contain 14? " + this.contains(14) + "\n");
  spruce.remove(14);
  console.log("Let's remove value 14. Does tree still contain 14?" + this.contains(14) + "\n");
  console.log("Contents of tree: " + this.toString() + "\n");
  console.log("Finally, let's multiply all values  within the tree by three! \n")
  var triple = function(x){return x * 3;}
  spruce.treeMap(triple);
  console.log("Contents of tree: " + this.toString() + "\n");
  console.log("Now clearing all contents of tree. \n")
  spruce.remove(8);
}
}
```

Then

```
var treeLib = require("./Tree");
treeLib.test();
```

However, when I attempt to run main.js, I receive the below error message:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
        at Object. (/Users/Anubis/Documents/COMP2406/Assignment 1/main.js:1:77)
        at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

I've been searching to find the syntax error in question, but have so far been unable to locate it.

Comment: Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button you used) are for **runnable in-browser code**, not for code that isn't runnable in the browser, and not for exception listings.

Answer (score 2):

The code has a basic syntax error on the second line:

```
    module.exports = {
    //Tree object with constructor
    var Tree = function(){
//  ^----- here
```

You can't declare variables within an object initializer.

Comment: This did the job. Thank you kindly!